# customer register success observer is not working

Tags: magento, observers

I'm trying to make an observer in my module
the method lunches on customer_register_success event
config file:

```
<events>
  <customer_register_success>
    <observers>
      <customer_register_success_handler>
        <type>Model</type>
        <class>cardnumber/observer</class>
        <method>GenerateCardNumber</method>
      </customer_register_success_handler>
    </observers>
  </customer_register_success>
</events>
```

and the observer file:

```
public function GenerateCardNumber($observer)
        {
            die;}
```

I don't know whats the problem 
using magento 1.8
any help
thanx in advance

Comment: Change <type>Model</type> to <type>model</type>

Comment: can you show your config.xml?

Answer (score 0):

This is the basic example for calling an observer

```
</global>    
<events>
                <controller_action_predispatch>
                    <observers>
                        <openstream_geo_model_html_after>
                            <type>singleton</type>
                            <class>geoip/observer</class>
                            <method>getLocationInfoByIp</method>
                        </openstream_geo_model_html_after>
                    </observers>
                </controller_action_predispatch>
            </events>
```

This has to be placed on ending of the global tag ie., outside of the global tag.

**Edited:**
Your observer file name has to be `Observer.php` and the function has to be as following:

```
class Openstream_GeoIP_Model_Observer
{
    public function controllerFrontInitBefore($observer) {
    die();
    }
   }
```

Class should not be extended. Just you need to mention class name as above. 
It will be better, if you can briefly explain the error that you are facing.

Comment: out of global !! in any tag it should be ??

Comment: I've found some thing
this event is dispatched only when a customer signs up for an account
can I make it happen when the admin creates a new customer account too??

Comment: here is the event for backend:adminhtml_customer_save_after .. I kept every thing in global tag FINALLY Worked .. thanx all

Answer (score 0):

RRammi,i thought,you have an issue with config.xml

i am write a example customer success observer...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <config>
<modules>
        <Namespace_Modulename>
            <version>0.0.1</version>
        </Namespace_Modulename>
    </modules>
        <global>
            <models>
                <your_module>
                    <class>Your_Module_Model</class>
                </your_module>
            </models>
        </global>
        <frontend>
            <events>
                <customer_register_success>
                    <observers>
                        <your_module>
                            <type>model</type>
                            <class>your_module/observer</class>
                            <method>customerSaveAfter</method>
                        </your_module>
                    </observers>
                </customer_register_success>
            </events>
        </frontend>
    </config>
```

Comment: I'm getting the event after the admin has added a new member
is it right to put it in frontend???
this didn't solve it
AND thanx for response

Comment: I've found some thing
this event is dispatched only when a customer signs up for an account
can I make it happen when the admin creates a new customer account too??

Comment: here is the event for backend:adminhtml_customer_save_after .. I kept every thing in global tag FINALLY Worked .. thanx all